# How to replicate iOS home screen behaviour?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I am currently working on a game in SpriteKit, where I need to move a sprite in response to touch (i.e when user swipes or pans anywhere in SKView.

I want to get the direction of pan (for swipe I know how to do it),so that the sprite will move according to pan (I have a path defined for the sprite if user pans or according to swipe if user swipes), the way touch in iOS appdrawer works i.e it responds to slightest of swipes and also pans (i.e when you pan forwards or backwards, it makes a decision whether you want to move to the next screen or not).

Is there any documentation or so? (I have gone through the UIGestureRecognizer documentation, but I haven't been able to find a way to implement it.)

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar on my MenuScene, I have 3 pages setup that the user can scroll through to get various game data. But I don't want the slightest touch to move the screen, it would be to jarring for the user. So I just watch the finger movements in the Touches functions and check if the movement is greater that an amount I designate as the minimum move amount and if it is greater than I scroll the page. In your case you could handle it as; if it is greater than the minimum move amount treat as a pan else treat it as a swipe

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    initialTouch = touch.location(in: self.view!)
    moveAmtY = 0
    moveAmtX = 0
    initialPosition = menuScroller.position
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    let movingPoint: CGPoint = touch.location(in: self.view!)
    moveAmtX = movingPoint.x - initialTouch.x
    moveAmtY = movingPoint.y - initialTouch.y

    //their finger is on the page and is moving around just move the scroller and parallax backgrounds around with them
    //Check if it needs to scroll to the next page when they release their finger
    menuScroller.position = CGPoint(x: initialPosition.x + moveAmtX, y: initialPosition.y)
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    //they havent moved far enough so just reset the page to the original position
    if fabs(moveAmtX) > 0 && fabs(moveAmtX) < minimum_detect_distance {
        resetPages()
    }

    //the user has swiped past the designated distance, so assume that they want the page to scroll
    if moveAmtX < -minimum_detect_distance {
        moveLeft()
    }
    else if moveAmtX > minimum_detect_distance {
        moveRight()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.